# Why did the writer use "would" instead of "loved"

Tags: construction

I can't understand why the phrase beneath is written that way.

> "She needed someone that would love her for more than just one night"

I've seen the same construction in other cases. Hope someone can help me.

Comment: Can you provide more context and a link to where you found this sentence? This sentence could mean many things, but only context can tell.

Comment: If that's your downvote, Alan, leaving a reason would be informative.

Answer (score 1):

This is a narrative of a past "event" (broadly construed).

**She needed someone that<sup>†</sup> would love her for more than just one night.**

Let's go back in time and describe it from a contemporary's vantage point:

**She *needs* someone who *will love* her for more than one night.**

What she needs is someone who will *continue to love* her. Simple **loves** would not clearly convey the idea of continuation expressed by future tense **will love**.

The word **would** is the past tense of **will**.   The narration of the past causes a shift of tense.  Now we are looking back at them in the past as they look towards their future.  **will love** => **would love**.

<sup>†</sup>I don't like using "that" with persons, though some people do.

Comment: This answer is wrong, it's not a past event, it's a hypothetical event.

Comment: You're nitpicking, I was talking about would. You said in your answer it was past tense. Grammatically correct, but not in the context of the question.

Answer (score -1):

The verb tense of *would love* is **[Simple conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uses_of_English_verb_forms#Simple_conditional)**, meaning it's not reality, but hypothetical. In this particular case it's something she wishes were the case, but isn't.

Based on your name I'll assume you speak Spanish, the translation would be:

> Necesitaba alguien que la amaría por más de una noche.

Comment: You're interpreting **needed** (past tense) as a *present* wish ("something she *wishes*").

Comment: I have not even mentioned the tense of need in my answer (and is irrelevant in the context of my answer), I would appreciate you judge my answer on merit, not on your not liking my downvote on yours.

Comment: I believe your not focusing on the tense of **need** is what caused you to say, in no uncertain terms, that my answer was wrong.  "Would" here is not a simple conditional, and not hypothetical. Consider: "She *needs* someone who *will fix* her roof.  She *needed* someone who *would fix* her roof.*

Comment: You keep obsessing on -need- when he's asking about -would-, it's in the title: "Why did the writer use “would” instead of “loved”" This is why, in no uncertain terms, your answer is wrong. Would is the past tense of will, but that has absolutely nothing to do with this question. The would in this construct is referring to a hypothetical.

Comment: Those conditionals are paired with an *if*-clause.  We have in the OP an example of tense consistency.

Comment: This is hopeless, I need someone who would understand English. <-- See what I did there?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/39973/discussion-between-j-a-terroba-and-tromano).